# How would I have my code remove the lowest integer?

Tags: python

```
def calc_average(scores)
  x = scores[1:]
  return (sum(x) / float(len(x)))
```

Here is some code that is supposed to find the average of a list of numbers, but not count the lowest. I'm not sure how to find the lowest number in the list, remove it from it, and then find the average of that. Can anyone help? Thanks! (The lowest number isn't always the first number in the list, that's the mistake I made...)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to literally remove the item from the list; you can just remove it from the calculation.

```
def calc_average(scores)
    return (sum(scores) - min(scores)) / float(len(x) - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would sort the list then romove the first element.

```
a = [ 3,2,6,3,8,7,2,1]
a.sort()
a = a[1:]
print a
print float(sum(a))/len(a)
```

The benefit of doing it this way, even though it is more work for just removing the single lowest value is that it is salable. Let's say you wanted to remove the lowest 2 or three values, that would be easy once you have the list sorted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the min() function to find the smallest value of a list, and then you can remove the value with the list.remove() function.

Check this out for reference https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min or https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#min

Comment: def calc_average(scores):
  y = min(scores)
  list.remove(y)
  x = scores[1:]
  return (sum(x) / float(len(x)))

Comment: For list.remove you need to put the actual name of your list variable.  So if your list is named x you would do x.remove(#) where # is the integer (i'm assuming) you want to remove.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
return float((sum(scores) - min(scores))) / (len(scores) - 1)
```

That finds the sum of all the scores, then removes the smallest score, before dividing by the number of scores after the removal.

Note there is no error-checking here, so this will not work properly for a list of length zero or one. That `float()` is there to ensure floating point division in Python 2.x. This uses the full speed of Python functions, but it does loop over the scores twice. A hand-coded function would be faster in looping only once but would slow down again in executing multiple commands.